# Octave or Matlab on Mac OS X 10.9.4

Tags: macos, neural-network, octave

I am currently reading Simon Haykin's Neural Networks and Learning Machines, 3rd edition and I would really like to do the experiments that are present in the book. 
In order to do that I need Matlab, but I believe that I could also use Octave.

I have been browsing the internet about Octave and Matlab installation on Mac OS X, but I have a few questions of my own.

I am a new Mac user, I have my mac for about 3-4 weeks and I was wondering why does Gatekeeper try to prevent Octave installation? Were there any situations of Octave harming Mac OS?

Also, what is the difference between installing octave via binary installer and homebrew?

I have considered purchasing Matlab, but the price in Europe is 530 Euro, which is a lot, and more expensive than buying in the US (around 500 Dollars). I am talking about the academic license. 
So that is a reason for looking into free software. On the other hand, I have read some posts that some Octave packages or functions don't work. So, should  I be worried about that? 
What are you experiences with Octave or Matlab on Mac?

Comment: read Octave's [wiki page about Mac OSX](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X). The binary installer is experimental (beta). A package manager such as homebrew is likely to be more reliable (if you're not use to a package manager you should try it). If you read that page it will also explain why gatekeeper blocks it and how to override it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I have read that wiki but was not able to find the answer to why does gatekeeper block the installation. Is it because it's from an unidentified source? Should I worry that octave will corrupt some parts of the system? As I said, I am new to Mac and am trying to be careful

Comment: From the Octave wiki "You may find instructions about how to do this on this page in the section labeled "How to open an app from a unidentified developer and exempt it from Gatekeeper"". So basically, the problem is that the person who prepared the Octave package is not registered with Apple. Anyway, I'd still recommend you use a package manager such as homebrew instead (but I'm a Linux and I'm biased towards them).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will probably go with Octave. I do have some experience with it and really liked it when I used it for Andrew Ng's Machine Learning class.

Comment: Go ahead with GNU Octave. Avoid closed source software whenever possible, specially when doing science.